# Uitableview cell text got hidden on edit Button

Tags: objective-c

When i try to delete any row - while clicking the edit button - the delete button appears and the text on right side truncated from the end.

I want to compress it automatically while delete button appears.

Comment: What do you mean by compress? Change its font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the textLabel property attributes to automatically truncate the middle of the string or set a smaller (minimum) font.

```
[[theCell textLabel] setMinimumFontSize:theSizeYouWant];
```

or

```
[[theCell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation];
```